# ReactJS: How to constantly check if token in localstorage has expired?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In ReactJS, is there a way to constantly check to see if the token saved in the localstorage has expired? If it has expired, would like to remove the token.

Came across the following but doesn't it only get triggered when the page gets reloaded?:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    //remove token
    return '';
}
```

Comment: What does _constantly_ mean to you?

Comment: why not use setInterval?

Comment: @Timo like while the application is running, keep checking

Comment: @Cleiton Sorry but could you elaborate more

Comment: How does this relate to ReactJS?  Also, how are you checking that the token is expired?  If you know when it expires, you can use setTimeout once... if you're validating against a server, then you need to give that detail... As to how to integrate with react, how are you managing your state?  Are you using a store, inline state?  What are you wanting to happen?

Comment: @Tracker1 Put ReactJS to see if there is a specific approach relevant to it. I would constantly load the token, and if it is undefined, I would remove it. But I want to be able to constantly load the token and check. For the state, I'm using Redux. I want to constantly check so if the user goes idle for some time, and tries to use it, want to log them out.

Comment: Create a redux middleware that runs your check using setinterval, or settimeout with looping, and then dispatches an event when it expires.

Comment: You can check on every componentDidMount. This way if a user is idle and token expires, the next page he tries to go to will check the token and see.

Comment: @Track1 Do you mind showing an example? So I can accept the answer/upvote as well.

Comment: @usedToBeFat is there a way to set it at the highest component so wouldn't have to set it to every componentDidMount?

Comment: yes see this answer to another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660745/user-authentication-for-api-from-react-app/40663342#40663342

Answer (score 3):

The following assumes you are using redux... you can create a middleware that will trigger an action when a token expires.. this will allow for you to handle a reducer downstream.  The redux approach is mainly because Redux is currently the most popular state management solution used with React.

```
// export the action type used as a const, so it can be imported for 
// the reducer to listen for...  The export const/key is more convenient
// then you can use a more namespaced string value to help prevent collisions
export const TOKEN_EXPIRED = 'tokenExpiredMiddleware_TokenExpired';

// redux middleware pattern (store) => (next) => (action) => result;
export default function expiredTokenMiddleware(store) {
  // here we only care about a handle to the store for store.dispatch
  // start checking every 15 seconds, probably want this configurable
  setInterval(checkToken.bind(null, store), 15000);

  // return a pass-through for the plugin, so other plugins work
  return (next) => (action) => next(action);
}

// export checkToken for testing... etc
// should probably be a separate module
export function checkToken(store) {
  var tokenId = ''; // TODO: Identify token
  var isExpired = true; // TODO: replace with function to get current state
  if (isExpired) {
    store.dispatch({
      type: TOKEN_EXPIRED,
      payload: { tokenId },
    });
  }
};
```

Then, when you do your createStore, you can just add this middleware which will emit the appropriate action, and you can handle it in your appropriate reducer... I do something similar for the window's resize/scroll events so that my size/position is always set.

This is using ES6+ syntax, since you're using React I think that is a fair assumption

Comment: Would probably do this, so you can proactively notify the user, in addition to the reactive solution pointed to by @usedToBeFat

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight. A few questions for clarification. First of all, should all of them placed in action creators? And could you elaborate a bit more on what a middleware pattern and `a pass-through for the plugin` are? And checkToken is simply an action creator, correct? And when does it get called?

Comment: I just prefer to dispatch something like this as an action creator, yes, this way you can handle it as-needed in your reducer.. the pass-through is just a function that passes all the rest through, ie doesn't do anything else as a plugin/extension...

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot use code running on the user's machine for security relevant use cases anyway, why not check the token only when it is used?

At some point you most likely load the token from local storage and use it to e.g. authenticate the session. Why not first check its validity then before using it?

This saves you the trouble of having an ongoing activity that checks the token, bundles related functionality and most likely reduces the complexity of your code.

After all, the token won't do any harm by just being stored in the browser's storage without being used, would it?